# Retrieving and Formatting Data Properly From MYSQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysqli

Okay so I'm trying to create a replica of the Billboard Hot 100. I have already a database and the page with the proper format I want. But when I tried to retrieve the data from the database, the format I used became a huge mess and a lot of errors appeared.

Here's my code:

```html
<div class="chartsList">
 <ul class="charts" style="list-style: none;">
  


  <?php
  $songQuery = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM songs ORDER BY sales DESC LIMIT 100");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($songQuery)) {
   

  $i = 2;
  foreach($songQuery as $songId) 

   echo "<li class='chartsRow'>
      <div style='width:10%;height:100%;float:left; text-align: center;color:black;font-size: 40px;line-height: 150px;font-weight: 600;'>$i</div>
     <img style='height: 30%; float: right; position: relative; top: 50; right: 89%;'src='" . $row['movement'] . "'>

     <img type='button' style='float: right;width: 25px;position: relative;top: 60;'onclick='myFunction()'src='assets/icons/expand.png'>
     <div style='width:90%; height:100%; display: block;''>

    <div style='width:15%;height:100%;float:left'>
     <img style='height: 90%;margin-top: 8;'src='". $row['coverArt'] . "'>
    </div>
    <div style='width:85%; height: 100%;margin-left: 26%;''>
     <a style='font-size: 30px; font-weight: 600; position: relative; top: 30;'>" . $row['title'] . "</a>
     <p style='position: relative;top: 10;''>" . $row['artist'] . "</p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div id='moreinfo'>
      <div class='lefty'> 
      <a>" . $row['lastWeek'] . "</a>
      <p>LAST WEEK</p>
    </div>
    <div class='lefty' style='border-left-style: solid;border-left-width: 1px;border-right-style: solid;border-right-width: 1px;border-right-color: #b7b7b7; border-left-color: #b7b7b7;'>
     <a>" . $row['peak'] . "</a>
     <p>PEAK POSITION</p>
    </div>
    <div class='lefty'>
     <a>" . $row['woc'] . "</a>
     <p>WEEKS ON CHART</p>
    </div>
    </div>
 

    </li>";

   $i = $i + 2;
  }

  ?>

 </ul>
   
</div>
```

Current Issue:

> "Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\billboard\hot-100.php
>   on line 52"

What I'm trying to achieve is something that looks like this: https://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100 but with the rows from 2-100 taking up 60% of the screen and a lower portion that can appear/disappear when clicking the extend icon.

Comment: "a lot of errors"...like what? Where? Do we have to guess?

Comment: Ids have to be **unique** (`<div id='moreinfo'>`)

Comment: @ADyson I'm sorry. Let me edit it

Comment: _"`mysqli_query`: **Returns `FALSE` on failure**. For successful `SELECT`, `SHOW`, `DESCRIBE` or `EXPLAIN` queries `mysqli_query()` will return a `mysqli_result` object. For other successful queries `mysqli_query()` will return `TRUE`."_ ([Source](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php))

Comment: I don't understand the `foreach`. You already looping over each row.

Comment: And to follow that up, if it's not set to throw an exception on the failure of a query, then using running `mysqli_error($con)` (only whenever it returns false from the query, of course) will tell you what the SQL error was. i.e. `if ($songQuery === false) { echo mysqli_error($con); die(); }`. (Of course this is naive but it works for now. Ideally, you log the error and then handle it more gracefully for the user experience, but that's a problem for later.) P.S. If you google your error message you'll find dozens, if not hundreds, of previous posts explaining what to do in this situation.

Comment: change `foreach($songQuery as $songId)` to `foreach($row as $songID)`? I dont know why your looping through the query response.

Comment: I also agree with waterloomatt above, the inner foreach appears to be redundant. The while loop will take you through each row one at a time. You don't need a second loop. What did you think the purpose of the foreach loop was? It's not clear.

Comment: It's also not clear why `$i` starts at 2 and then increases by 2 each time. If that's intended to show the chart position then clearly it's going to be wrong - it'll start at 2, and then be followed by 4, 6, 8 etc. But also it resets on each new row, so actually it'll just always print 2. If this is a counter of the chart position, then initialise it as 1 _before_ the while loop, and then increase it by one each time just before the while loop ends (i.e. `$i++;` just before the closing bracket of the while loop).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what all the errors are but the main issue here is that you need to turn on error reporting and check for connection errors before trying to use the query and then also check for errors after running the query but before accessing the result set.

I have removed the inner `foreach` loop because it is redundant. You can create a counter by simply incrementing a variable. See comments in code.

```
<?php
// Turn on error reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Turn MySQL errors into PHP exceptions
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

// I assume you have a procedural-style connection setup here.
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
?>

<div class="chartsList">
    <ul class="charts" style="list-style: none;">

        <?php
        $counter = 0;
        $songQuery = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM songs ORDER BY sales DESC LIMIT 100");

        // Now, check if your query has an error
        if ($songQuery === false){
            die('Error in query: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($songQuery)) {
            // Your HTML appears to be malformed. I'm getting all sorts of errors in my IDE.
            // Removing the HTML here but you should be able to merge that back in without issues.

            // If you need a counter to display row numbers, you can just create one.
            // Notice I created a $counter variable above.
            // increment it by:
            //    $counter++; to increment by 1 OR
            //    $counter = $counter + 2; to increment by 2

            // Now, use $row['column_name'] where you need it.
        } ?>

    </ul>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Sounds like you're also having CSS/styling issues. Get the DB query going first and then ask a new, specific question with more details including screen shots.